# SVG clip-path resizing issue

Tags: canvas, svg, clip

I'm using a .png mask for Safari/Chrome and (as Firefox doesn't support the use of .pngs for masking) I'm targeting Firefox with a clip-path svg to shape the canvas. The demo can be viewed [here](http://happycell.info/clippathdemo.html) .

The .png mask is behaving as expected when the window is resized, however the svg clip-path does not. Once the window is resized the clip-path is retaining its original coordinates and not scaling with its DIV, even if the canvas is scaling.

Can anyone help me out with this as I've spent quite some time to try and get this responsive feature working with no success?

My project demo markup is:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: inherit;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  overflow: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#happycell {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-height: 992px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("../images/happycell_flask.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: inherit;
  background-size: contain;
}
#happycell img {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.experiment {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-mask-image: url("../images/happycell_mask.png");
  -o-mask-image: url("../images/happycell_mask.png");
  -moz-mask-image: url("../images/happycell_mask.png");
  mask-image: url("../images/happycell_mask.png");
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100%;
  clip-path: url("../images/clip.svg#svgClip");
}
#c {
  position: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
#c img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG clip-path-->

<svg width="500" height="992" viewBox="0 0 500 992" viewPort="0 0 500 992" x="100" y="100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <defs>
  <clipPath id="svgClip" transform="translate(96 340)" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<path id="svgPath" d="M484.3,370.9c-9-26.7-18.1-57.9-26.8-88.2c-5.8-20.3-11.4-39.4-16.6-55.9c-4.3-13.8-7.9-26.9-11.3-39.7
c-4.7-17.3-9.5-35.3-16.3-55c-4.9-14.2-9.9-31-15.2-48.8c-3.7-12.4-7.5-25.2-11.4-37.4c-3.6-11.4-7-23.7-10.2-35.4
c-0.4-1.4-0.8-2.4-1.2-3.4c0,0-8.4-7.2-123.1-7.2S125.8,7.4,125.8,7.4c-1.3,3.9-2.6,7.2-3.7,11.1c-6.4,21.5-15.7,51.9-22.6,72.3
c-12.4,36.8-24.4,79-36,119.9c-2.4,8.4-4.8,16.8-7.2,25.2c-5.7,20-13,43.1-20.6,67.5c-8.5,27-17.3,55-23.6,77.8l-0.8,2.9
c-7.9,28.5-14.7,53.1-9.7,82.2c4,23.4,20.5,46.1,40.8,56.2c15.6,7.8,32.8,15.6,52.6,19.8c18,3.8,39.2,7.9,60.7,9.1
c8.4,0.5,17.1,1.1,25.5,1.8c17.1,1.3,34.8,2.7,52,2.7c2.7,0,5.3,0,7.9-0.1c41.3-1.1,85.8-2.7,131.3-7.1
c28.4-2.7,70.4-14.3,95.7-33.3c20.8-15.6,31.2-37.3,31.7-66.1C500.3,422,491.8,393,484.3,370.9z"/>
  </clipPath>

</defs>
</svg>


<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div class="info"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="happycell">
    <div class="experiment">
      <canvas id="c"></canvas>
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code you've posted is incomplete and inaccurate.  Please post both the HTML/CSS code that you're trying to clip and the SVG clip path you're using.

Comment: I suspect things will work better for you if you use objectBoundingBox units rather than userSpaceOnUse units.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the clip-path with clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox", but the canvas content is now not rendering. In relation to the clip-path units, is the object referenced in "objectBoundingBox" the DIV containing the mask?

Comment: You can't change from one unit system to another without changing the contents. What you've done is like changing from metres to inches without changing all the values to the new unit system so everything is now the wrong size. All the values in the path d attribute need to change to be appropriate for the new unit system which is basically now 0..1

Comment: Many thanks for your help Robert. I've changed the path to a standard  geometric shape and the clip-path scaling now works perfectly. My original SVG clip-path was created using Adobe Illustrator so my next challenge will be to recreate that clip-path shape using acceptable coordinates for objectBoundingBox.